# How do I set up this mixing problem using Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Okay so I have a problem that I need help setting up on. If you solved it and also showed work that would be incredibly helpful so I can check myself as I work along.

The Problem:

A 20L vessel contains 16L of Nitrogen and 4L of Oxygen. If pure nitrogen is pumped into the vessel at .1L per second, is thoroughly mixed, and withdrawn at the same rate it is added, after how many minutes is the vessel 99% Nitrogen?

My Wrong Solution:

I've tried solving it before but I was marked wrong. I thought for mixing problems there was a formula dx/dt=rici-roco, where ri and ro are rate ins and rate outs and ro and ci and co are concentrations ins and outs. So I had ri=ro=.1L per second (or 6 Liters per minute) and ci as 1 since it was 100 percent nitrogen coming in. Co is defined as x/(vo-(ri-ro)t) where vo is initial volume of the vessel which I had as 16 but it might have been 20. I plugged in those values and made the equation separable.

Anyway, I'm sorry if I've made reading this question difficult. I'm just trying to include as much information as possible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it say $0.1$ litres per second? Then it is $6$ litres per minute.

Comment: Oops that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\left(t\right)$ be the concentration of Nitrogen. Then
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}\left(t\right)=\frac{.1}{20}\left(1-x\right).
$$
and
$$
x\left(0\right)=\frac{16}{20}.
$$
You can solve this using the usual methods to get
$$
x\left(t\right)=1-0.2e^{-0.005t}.
$$
We need to find $t$ s.t. $x\left(t\right)=0.99$. Then
\begin{align*}
0.99 & =1-0.2e^{-0.005t}\\
e^{-0.005t} & =\frac{1}{20}\\
t & =\frac{\ln20}{0.005}\approx599.146\text{ seconds}.
\end{align*}

Comment: That helped a lot! Thanks @par .

Comment: Please accept if correct.

Comment: I'll find out tomorrow if it's correct but the math seems right.